# Blazor bind data to collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, blazor

I'm trying to generate forms with Blazor programmatically, and I'm running into an issue where I need to bind an InputText value to a member of a collection such as:

```
@foreach (var prop in formProperties)
{
    <InputText id=@prop.Name @bind-Value="form.Responses[prop.Name]" />
}
```

However, I get the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: The provided expression contains a InstanceMethodCallExpression1 which is not supported. FieldIdentifier only supports simple member accessors (fields, properties) of an object.
```

Is it possible to bind the input to a collection of some sort?

Comment: Yes, create a component that takes (binds) the `formProperties`. Then create a child component that takes `prop`. The parent component foreach's through the collection and renders a child component for each `prop`. The child component can then handle the rendering of the correct `<InputText>` fields for each property of prop and bind them.

Comment: Where would the `<InputText>` fields be binded to? And how could I get that data to the parent?

Comment: Using Component-to-Component Data Binding. Blazor provides two-way data binding between components called [Chained Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#chained-bind) Through an eventcallback and by using the naming convention property`Changed` you can notify the parent on updates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Running into a similar issue where I'm trying to build a table based on a dictionary of attributes, I came across [this reply](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12000#issuecomment-509709972) from Steve.

Basically what you can do is introduce a new type called e.g.

```
public class FormResponse
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming you now create a dictionary of `FormResponse` on your `form` object, you can then do this:

```
@foreach (var prop in formProperties)
{
    <InputText id="@prop.Name" @bind-Value="form.Responses[prop.Name].Value" />
}
```

Which is arguably more straightforward than creating a new component with Chained Binding.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot use the `<InputText/>` component for more complex accessors presently.

However, if you don't mind handling your own validation/notification code, you can roll your own by:

- Changing the `<InputText/>` to an `<input/>`
- Use `@bind` instead of `@bind-Value`

Using your code:

```
@foreach (var prop in formProperties)
{
    <input id=@prop.Name @bind="form.Responses[prop.Name]" />
}
```

Again, you will loose change notifications, and validation, and all connection to the EditForm and EditContext.

You can also go the route that @dennis1679 suggested, creating a sub component. I am curious what the [Chained Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#parent-to-child-binding-with-component-parameters) integration with the top level form/model validation would be like in practice with. I haven't played with that yet.

FYI, I did a quick search, and didn't see the issue (likely a feature) in github, but when I find it, I will update this.